# How do I break from this while loop?

Tags: swift

I have this code nested in a while statement with if statements under it depending on its input. I want to be able to press a letter on the keyboard without my code throwing an error as the only input it takes is double. I have tried try and do but when I implement the code it throws a bunch of errors from the following code depending on it. I want to be able to break when a letter is detected instead of inducing a fetal error.

`let initialValue = Double(readLine()!)`

How can I do this?

Comment: Show more code so we have some context.

Comment: Also pretty sure you meant fatal not fetal.

Comment: @Atmas I laughed harder than I should have

Comment: @Aheze You're not the only one. Though inappropriate for this thread, I feel like I learned a new phrase that I have really been missing in my fathering lexicon.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from a Java background, I would suggest you find a way in your loop to first capture the output of readLine() in its native format (probably NOT a double.. likely a String) and then utilize an isDouble() function to check it to first determine if it's actually a double before performing the Double-cast as you have there.

This will allow you to avoid what I'm guessing is a fatal "this is not a number" style error.